# How can I check the distance from each one of the cubes depending on what cube I'm closer to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The cubes are in formation of a big square to create some kind of border so the player can't move further.
transform is the player the script is attached to the player.

When I move the player to one of the cubes close to it the distance is about 95 but it should 0.1f or 0.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class DistanceCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] cubes;
    public GameObject descriptionTextImage;
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cubes.Length; i++)
        {
            var dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, cubes[i].transform.position);

            if (dist <= 0.1f)
            {
                descriptionTextImage.SetActive(true);
                text.text = "I can't move.";
            }
            else
            {
                text.text = "";
                descriptionTextImage.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm using a break point on the line :

```
if (dist <= 0.1f)
```

dist is a bit more then 95. Maybe the distance is checked to another cube or in another point on the cube?

[image: Cubes wall]

Comment: are the dists for *all* the cubes 95? if you keep clicking breakpoint you should be getting different values for the different cubes as you loop through. Also I'm sure there's a measuring tool in unity where you can check if the distances are accurate. Perhaps it's a unit issue?

Comment: @QrowSaki The distance is not the same I just added some cubes to create kind of square as a border where the player will not be able to move over it.  I can make later the square perfect accurate but for now it's not critic.  I just want to make that no matter where the player is going and collide at any point in the any of cubes to show some text.

Comment: I tried also OnTriggerEnter in the script but it didn't work only if I check on all cubes the IsTrigger to true but then the player will not stop he will be able to walk through the cubes . It will get into the ontriggerenter but the player will move through the cubes.

Comment: are you trying to do collision detection manually? Have you tried using a RigidBody? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html

Answer (score 1):

You are checking all cubes every time and using same "dist" variable every time.
So it detects deistance being less then 0.1f, but goes on and changes value of dist to test another cube.This is why you are getting higher values despite being right next to a cube.
You need 4 distance variables that are each measuring distances to its specific cube and do something if either of them gets too short.
Another flaw is that you are measuring distance to a point in a box, so depending which side of a box you are its going to be showing different values.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest instead of using cube Transforms, use their Colliders instead. And then I'd be looking for the closest point on the collider bounds. As it currently stands, you're checking for the distance of this object, to the origin of the cube, and it sounds to me like you simply want to find the distance to the cube/collider in general.

First, change the field type for your cubes:

```
public BoxCollider[] cubes;
```

Then find the distance like this:

```
var closestPoint = cubes[ i ].ClosestPointOnBounds ( transform.position );
var distance = Vector3.Distance( transform.position, closestPoint );
```

Now you should be getting a distance to the closest point to the cube/collider.

More information on `ClosestPointOnBounds` can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPointOnBounds.html) at the Unity docs.